# How to update symfony/dom-crawler 2.5 on 2.6 (laravel 4.2)?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4

How to update symfony/dom-crawler 2.5 on 2.6  (laravel 4.2)

I tried: composer require `symfony/dom-crawler 2.6`

ERROR:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework == 4.2.17.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.17].
    - laravel/framework v4.2.17 requires symfony/dom-crawler 2.5.* -> no matching package found.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires symfony/dom-crawler 2.5.* -> no matching package found.
```

...

```
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: You have a conflict between packages - Laravel 4.2 wants the crawler to be on version 2.5, but you want 2.6. A short term solution is to fork Laravel, hack the `composer.json` to bump up the crawler version, and then run the Laravel tests to see if it still passes. If it does, modify your own software to fetch Laravel from your fork. Finally, log an issue with the Laravel folks to see if they will consider upgrading the crawler, so you can switch your own Composer file back to Laravel, and remove your fork.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so.